Why is Python package naming so weird?
I haven't done a lot with python so I always have trouble figuring out how to install packages.   Most samples I look at have something like this:
import cv2
import pytesseract

Silly me things this should work to add the libraries to my virtual environment:
pip install cv2 pytesseract

But of course that doesn't work since 'cv2' isn't really a pip package.   So I have to pause and do some google searching to eventually find the actual name of the package so I can install them:
pip install opencv-python pytesseract

Is there some reason for this inconsistency?   Is there a repository I can head to when I have a statement like 'import cv2' that will quickly tell me the package to install?  This seems to happen quite a bit where the names differ from what is imported.


Is there some reason for this inconsistency?

The reason is very simple — packages are created by people and people have many different reasons. Just one example:
There was a templating library called "CheetahTemplate". Its main import was import Cheetah. The distribution was named Cheetah. There were major versions 1 (it was long ago, before PyPI) and 2. I was just a user. Later I became a maintainer and updated the package to work with Python 3 (with a lot of help from community). I changed the major version to 3. The import still was import Cheetah for obvious backward compatibility reason. I wanted to release distribution under the same name "Cheetah" but its maintainer was uncooperative so I decided to publish the distribution under new name "Cheetah3". The import still was import Cheetah. Package Cheetah3 was already registered but I asked its owner and he was more responsive; for some time I was publishing new releases.
Later I was painfully kicked two times (don't ask) and got 2 reasons to change the distribution name once again. Now it's called CT3. Its main import still is import Cheetah! I hope the story was not too long and up to the point. :-)

Is there a repository I can head to when I have a statement like 'import cv2' that will quickly tell me the package to install?

No. Who would maintain such a repository, for what reason, and who gonna pay for it to be public? People who regularly install packages maintain subsets of such a repository in their heads.
There're two ways to map imports to distribution names. You've already tried one — internet search. The other one is — read the code. Alas, these are the only ways.

Thanks for the explanation.    I guess having the repository be wherever pip stores its information would make sense.   As you can tell I'm not very experienced with the whole python ecosystem.  I would think the repository where it pulls packages from should be able to list packages that have certain imports.  Can't that lead to conflicts if the same import name is used in more than one package?  I found pip_search which seems to only look at package name.  Using the search on pypi.or gives me 2119 projects for opencv and 1232 for 'cv2', both without showing the package I think I want early

Interesting link though it's 3 years old now on the funding for PyPi: https://dustingram.com/articles/2021/04/14/powering-the-python-package-index-in-2021/

@JasonGoemaat The only way to have such a repository is for you to create one and start collecting mappings from imports to package names. Publish it for everyone and provide a way to update it; at least by sending you a notification. Or may be write a script that downloads every package from PyPI and finds out the mapping. Get ready for the same import in different packages like import Crypto in different cryptographic packages. Be prepared for the similar import in different packages like import Crypto and import crypto.
